# Verify phone Number before Registration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a project in asp .Net framework where client is asking for mobile number verification before registration. If the mobile is verified then user can register or else can not.

so linking that to the identity user table and async with it keeping the verified mobile, could not relate things to one another codding-Ly. how to do it?

Thanx for the suggestion Tavershima , I thought if some async will verify and wait until verification and registration is done then update all at once , but it seems not possible as u said so am not sure , and some developers marking this question as down I don't know what is the problem with this , that is disappointing

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to verify a phone number before registration is a kind of trying to verify emails before registration. If you have ever made an authentication system before or used `Asp.Net Identity` you will see that it has an option for verifying email before login.

```
....AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
});
```

. This property makes sure that a user verifies his email before he can login. In your case,the reverse is the case. You can then write additional logic to for your app to generate a confirmation code and send to the phone number to then be entered back to finish the registration. This will prevent the user from entering a false phone number. In that accord, you have to register with an [sms provider](https://www.bulksms.com/) which will bill you based on your usage or subscription based.

Comment: you are right but I meant in the question how can I save temporary data like loginid and mobile id and name for example and check if the user verified the phone number then complete the registration by saving data permanently or else discard it after sometime ,